# Scoring rule for comparing two distribution of probabilities

Tags: distributions, scoring-rules

I need help with figuring out a proper scoring rule for the following task.

- There are 11 possible outcomes.
- There is a true probability distribution over these outcomes (known to me but not you). For example, let's say that the true distribution is: 2%, 4%, 8%, 12%, 14%, 20%, 14%, 12%, 8%, 4%, 2%
- I ask you to provide your best estimate for the probability distribution over these outcomes. For example, you might estimate: 0%, 0%, 2%, 12%, 18%, 33%, 14%, 10%, 6%, 4%, 1%.

My research suggests that a quadratic scoring rule (QSR) might be appropriate in cases such as this. However, as I understand it, the QSR is appropriate only in cases where a single event actually ends up occurring. In this case, I want to compare two distributions in which there is no event that ends up occurring.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of this scoring? For what use will it be put?

Comment: I would like to reward you in cash for accuracy. The closer your estimated distribution is to the true distribution, the more cash you get.

Comment: That's a circular answer: how exactly do you intend to quantify "accuracy"?  Unless you tell us specifically, we cannot determine an appropriate scoring rule; and if we propose any such rule, we are offering (unfounded) opinions about what "accuracy" might mean to you.

Comment: Perhaps you have revealed one of the problems I am having: Defining "accuracy". Can you tell me a couple of different ways in which accuracy might be defined in this context?